# firebase Admin SDK installation in laravel throwing error

Tags: laravel, firebase, sdk, installation, admin

Can anyone help me on this..
I was trying to use cloud storage on my laravel application..
using this command `sudo composer require kreait/firebase-php ^5.0`
throwing some errors

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install kreait/firebase-php 5.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install kreait/firebase-php 5.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install kreait/firebase-php 5.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install kreait/firebase-php 5.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install kreait/firebase-php 5.x-dev|remove google/cloud v0.105.0
    - Conclusion: don't install kreait/firebase-php 5.x-dev|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - Installation request for kreait/firebase-php ^5.0 -> satisfiable by kreait/firebase-php[5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.2.0, 5.x-dev].
    - kreait/firebase-php 5.x-dev requires google/cloud-storage ^1.14 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-storage[v1.14.0, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.16.1, v1.17.0, v1.18.0, v1.19.0, v1.20.0, v1.20.1].
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.14.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.15.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.16.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.16.1|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.17.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.18.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.19.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.20.0|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - don't install google/cloud-storage v1.20.1|don't install google/cloud v0.105.0
    - Installation request for google/cloud (locked at v0.105.0) -> satisfiable by google/cloud[v0.105.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do no show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself, and format it so it's easy to ready, copy, and search.